# Astrophysics after Aerospace Engineering?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate

I'm a second year aerospace engineering undergraduate student. 
I like this course because it might get me to the space industry; but it is not as closely tied to the subject of space sciences as astronomy/astrophysics courses are.

Of course I don't want to abandon my course, so I was wondering how difficult it is to get a graduate degree in astrophysics after I'm done with aerospace. I know I'd be lacking some knowledge but I feel like the trade-off is worth it.

I can *consider* abandoning my course and going to physics instead, but that's a last resort.

Any advice is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This might depend on where you are. The two fields are pretty different.

Comment: @Buffy I'm in central Europe.

Comment: Is double-majoring an option?

Comment: If you want to work in the space industry (and I take this to mean planning/designing/building space missions, rocketry etc) then aerospace engineering is *far* more relevant than astrophysics.

Comment: @Nat No way. Aerospace and Astrophysics are both academically brutal and quite different, so there's not enough intersection.

Comment: @astronat I understand, but isn't it really hard to actually get into the space industry? It feels like a gamble, almost.

Comment: Assuming you live in America, If you have any problems getting into NASA or Space X right away, you could always get some experience working at Lockheed Martin, Northrop Grumman, Boeing, etc.  I don't think there is any gamble getting an Aerospace Engineering degree.

Comment: @GaryDrocella I don't live in America, and I'm afraid their security clearance levels would highly limit my employability in the companies you mentioned.

Comment: @Victor SCS Where do you live if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @GaryDrocella I don't mind at all, Right now I'm located in Portugal; I'll probably be able to get a citizenship by the time I get the degree.

Comment: @Victor SCS According to this: https://news.clearancejobs.com/2018/07/07/can-immigrants-obtain-a-security-clearance/.  It is possible to get a security clearance, and I don't think Portugal will raise any red flags.  Keywords are "I think", though.  Is there anyway you can become a citizen sooner?  Getting a security clearance will be a very, very long and boring process for you.  It might take possibly even 2 years or more for you to get the clearance.  That's why I am wondering whether you can get your citizenship sooner.

Comment: @GaryDrocella I think it's very unlikely that I'll get the citizenship sooner, but I'm not worried about that; as long as in the end I'm able to do what I want, I'll be fine. I'm very inclined in the direction of your suggestion; getting experience in certain jobs to raise the odds of an ideal one. Though, maybe it's because I'm inside the box, but I'm still quite uneasy about that.

Answer (score 2):

It's doable. Won't be easy, but doable. Get as much background in physics as you can during your undergraduate studies. You probably won't be able to take e.g. Quantum Field Theory, but it doesn't sound like you're aiming for these theoretical branches of astrophysics anyway.

Example from the [MIT Physics PhD webpage](http://web.mit.edu/physics/prospective/graduate/faq.html#faq.gen1):

> **Must I have a degree in physics in order to apply to this graduate program?**
>
> Prior to starting their Physics doctoral studies here, our successful applicants generally hold a Bachelor of Science degree in Physics or have taken many Physics classes, if they have majored in another discipline. The most common other majors are astronomy, engineering, mathematics and chemistry. Bachelor of Science degrees may be 3-year or 4-year degrees, depending on the education structure of the country they are in.

Comment: Can you take classes after you finish your last undergrad class? So as to not overload; aerospace is mental as it is

Comment: @VictorSCS you'd have to check your institute's policies - I'd guess yes, you can delay graduation, but you'd have to pay tuition fees.

Comment: Jesus. I guess my best option is to take at least 1 extra curricular physics discipline per year then. Either that or get a second bachelors in physics after I finish, which would take me 2 years in the same university (I've checked it). I'm really unsure though so if you have any advice on this I'd be very thankful.

Comment: @VictorSCS I'd suggest 1) talking to someone in the field who you want to join and 2) attempting the graduate studies without getting the physics BSc. A physics BSc is likely to teach you a lot of things you won't need, so don't do it if you don't have to.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the BSc was a bad idea.
I'll probably just delay my graduation and do one more semester just with the extra physics disciplines I'd need for the masters. I've talked to the course director and he said this is a good idea, so I'm going for it. Thank you!